# Symbol for "such that"

Tags: notation, soft-question

I was taught, long ago, to use a symbol similar to this "$\Large ᚃ$" meaning "such that" and, alternatively, the symbol "|". I am unable to find examples using the former.

Does anyone know about it? I am curious about the time it was introduced and whether or not it is used nowadays.

Comment: I expect that there are dozens or even hundreds of different ways that authors, teachers, and more have written the phrase "such that" symbolically.  I remember one of my teachers using something which looked similar to the kanji for the number seven for this purpose: 七.  So long as it is defined, anything can be used.  I am personally unaware of anything formal or standardized for this.  To emphasize, these are typically shorthand and informal and should probably not be used in any sort of formal writing.

Comment: I personally always write it in words so "[...] such that [...]"

Comment: French people use the symbol "/"

Comment: In set-builder notation I prefer the colon "$:$", especially when absolute values (e.g. $|x|$ ) or norms (e.g. $\|x\|$... LaTex \|x\| ) are mentioned.. For example $\{x\in\Bbb Q : |x|>1\}$. And when talking to the mathematically ignorant (which is most people), I say "for which" instead of "such that". In colloquial English, you almost never hear "such that".

Comment: By the way, $|$ only really means “such that” in set-builder notation (and related notations). I have never seen a professional mathematician use it outside of that.

Comment: @EikeSchulte It was in high school, I don't remember the full context. Maybe the teacher noted that.